Blazor Webassembly Cache Cleanup issue
I've a Blazor Webassembly application without PWA (.NET 8). We are facing issues in deployment, that whenver a new version is deployed the cache storage in client(browser) doesn't get refresh automatically, hence having staled pages from previous user sessions.
I want the cache to be cleared on client side each time a new deployment/new version released.
I've gone through below articles/nuget packages:-

https://whuysentruit.medium.com/blazor-wasm-pwa-adding-a-new-update-available-notification-d9f65c4ad13
https://blog.razorcomponents.net/2019/02/handling-version-updates-in-blazor-pwa.html
https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.PWA.Updater

But all the above works with PWA, our application is without PWA hence its not feasible to use the solution provided in above articles.
Can anyone please share their experience and how they resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Have you considered using timestamps when you release new versions to solve this problem? Like <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css?v=1.0.0.1"> and <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js?v=1.0.0.1"></script>.
